# How to change next image once it is time out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="cont">
<ul>
    <li  class="Show"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="1" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="2" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="3" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="4" /></li>           
</ul>  

.Show {
   display: block;
 }
 li {
   display: none;
 }

 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 setInterval(function() {   
   jQuery('.Show').removeClass('Show').next().addClass('Show');
 }, 1000);
});
```

Hi, I want the images to be loop once all the images are over, it should start from begining again
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For repetitive action you can use **[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)** :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     setInterval(function() {   
       jQuery('.Show').removeClass('Show').next().addClass('Show');
     }, 3000);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66sqf/18/)**

And if you want to show first image after last image display, then try below code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

   setInterval(function() {
      if(jQuery('.Show').next().length==0)
       {
           jQuery('.Show').removeClass('Show');
           $('li:first').addClass('Show');
       }
      else
      {
        jQuery('.Show').removeClass('Show').next().addClass('Show');
      }
   }, 3000);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66sqf/47/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var my_interval = setInterval( function () {
        var current = $(".Show");
        current.removeClass("Show");
        console.log(current.next());

        if ( current.next().length == 0 ) {
            clearInterval(my_interval);
        }

        current.next().addClass("Show");
    },3000 );
 });
```

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YPRLL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your slider effect to restart from the first image when you reach the end, you should try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     setInterval(toggleNext, 3000);
 });

function toggleNext(){
    var current = $('li.Show');
    current.removeClass('Show');
    var next = current.next();
    if(!next.is('li')) 
        next = $('.cont ul li').first();
    next.addClass('Show');
}
```